# Why is apple asking for security questions when using fastlane to submit app to testflight?

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-pilot

I use fastlane `pilot` to submit my apps to appstore. I have a circle-ci job that runs fastlane script and submits the apps.

I also created a developer account and added it to my team and gave `app manager` access to it, as my primary account has 2 step verification enabled. ([As suggested in fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/#separate-apple-id-for-ci)).

All of this worked previously and I was able to submit my app to testflight and test.

But all of a sudden from today, fastlane started to fail submitting my apps and I am getting this message after fastlane enters my email in portal (`Service key is empty`), and then the build in ci fails with this error message.

> Invalid 2 step response {"securityQuestions"=>{"questions"=>[{"id"=>132, "question"=>"Security Question 1?", "number"=>1, "userDefined"=>false}, {"id"=>145, "question"=>"Security Question 2?", "number"=>3, "userDefined"=>false}]}, "crResetEnabled"=>false, "resetSecurityQuestionsSupportLink"=>"http://support.apple.com/some-link"}

Comment: try upgrading Fastlane version

Comment: Tried but didn't work